# concat distinct string that are in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe1

```
name    age
XYZ     20
XYZ     25
ABC     30
ABC     35
```

How do I join the `name` column that contain distinct values?

desired result

```
XYZ, ABC
```

Comment: `','.join(df['name'].unique())`?